# PHP Soap complex params with repeated keys

Tags: php, soap-client

I need to generate the following XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://services.bloomberg.com/datalicense/dlws/ps/20071001">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:submitGetHistoryRequest>
            <ns1:headers>
                <ns1:daterange>
                    <ns1:period>
                        <ns1:start>2018-05-08</ns1:start>
                        <ns1:end>2018-05-08</ns1:end>
                    </ns1:period>
                </ns1:daterange>
            </ns1:headers>
            <ns1:fields>
                <ns1:field>PX_LAST</ns1:field>
            </ns1:fields>
            <ns1:instruments>
                <ns1:instrument>
                    <ns1:id>US0000000002</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:yellowkey>Equity</ns1:yellowkey>
                    <ns1:type>ISIN</ns1:type>
                </ns1:instrument>
                <ns1:instrument>
                    <ns1:id>US0000000001</ns1:id>
                    <ns1:yellowkey>Equity</ns1:yellowkey>
                    <ns1:type>ISIN</ns1:type>
                </ns1:instrument>
            </ns1:instruments>
        </ns1:submitGetHistoryRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I use PHP 7.1.17 and SoapClient.

I can not pass options to SoapClient, as the `instrument` key is repeated and PHP's associated array can not have same key twice. I tried constructing object and setting `instrument` properties as `SoapVar`, but it generates incorrect XML. Here is code and result:

```
$options = new \stdClass();
$options->headers = new \stdClass();
$options->headers->daterange = new \stdClass();
$options->headers->daterange->period = new \stdClass();
$options->headers->daterange->period->start = '2018-05-08';
$options->headers->daterange->period->end = '2018-05-08';
$options->fields = new \stdClass();
$options->fields->field = 'PX_LAST';

//first instrument
$instrument = new \stdClass();
$instrument->id = 'US0000000002';
$instrument->type = 'ISIN';
$instrument->yellowkey = 'Equity';
$options->instruments[] = new \SoapVar(
    $instrument,
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
    'stdClass',
    "http://soapinterop.org/xsd",
    "instrument"
);
//second instrument
$instrument = new \stdClass();
$instrument->id = 'US0000000001';
$instrument->type = 'ISIN';
$instrument->yellowkey = 'Equity';
$options->instruments[] = new \SoapVar(
    $instrument,
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
    'stdClass',
    "http://soapinterop.org/xsd",
    "instrument"
);
```

`<ns1:instruments/>` remains empty in resulting XML:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://services.bloomberg.com/datalicense/dlws/ps/20071001">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:submitGetHistoryRequest>
            <ns1:headers>
                <ns1:daterange>
                    <ns1:period>
                        <ns1:start>2018-05-08</ns1:start>
                        <ns1:end>2018-05-08</ns1:end>
                    </ns1:period>
                </ns1:daterange>
            </ns1:headers>
            <ns1:fields>
                <ns1:field>PX_LAST</ns1:field>
            </ns1:fields>
            <ns1:instruments/>
        </ns1:submitGetHistoryRequest>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

How can I pass options to SoapClient, to generate XML with repeated `instrument` keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. Turns out when you pass an ordered array (not associative one) as object's property, as many XML nodes are generated using that property's name, as number of elements in the array. So instead of building `SoapVar` objects and putting them into `instruments[]` array, I just assigned array of instruments to `instruments` as `instrument` property:

```
$options->instruments = new \stdClass();

//first instrument
$instrument = new \stdClass();
$instrument->id = 'US0000000002';
$instrument->type = 'ISIN';
$instrument->yellowkey = 'Equity';

$options->instruments->instrument[] = $instrument;

//second instrument
$instrument = new \stdClass();
$instrument->id = 'US0000000001';
$instrument->type = 'ISIN';
$instrument->yellowkey = 'Equity';

$options->instruments->instrument[] = $instrument;
```

I build instruments in a `foreach` loop. Btw converting array to object instead of building `stdClass` also works fine:

```
$options->instruments->instrument[] = (object)[
    'id' => 'US0000000001',
    'type' => 'ISIN',
    'yellowkey' => 'Equity'
]
```